# Can't trigger javascript function on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code, that dynamically creates checkboxes based on unique values in an array. The trigger function does not work and I have no idea why. I need to trigger another function based on which checkbox was selected.

```js
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

function filter_based_on_selection(selected_box_id) {
  console.log("Selected option : ");
  console.log(selected_box_id);
}

array2 = ['Z1', 'Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3', 'Z3', 'Z4', 'Z4', 'Z4', 'Z5', 'Z5', 'Z5', 'Z6', 'Z7', 'Z7'];

var unique_account_groups = array2.filter(onlyUnique);

console.log("Unique Account Groups found : ");

console.log(unique_account_groups);

for (var prop in unique_account_groups) 
{
    jQuery("#filters").append('<div class="checkbox"><label><input class="list-group2-item" id= ' + unique_account_groups[prop] + 'onclick="filter_based_on_selection(this.id)" type="checkbox" value="">' + unique_account_groups[prop] + '</label></div>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filters">
  <div class="list-group2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. There is no 'trigger' function in the code you've shown 2. Why are you using the outdated `onclick` attribute instead of attaching your events using unobtrusive methods? 3. Don't use `click` events on radio or checkboxes. Use `change`.

Comment: Just inspect the element and you could see this `id="Z1onclick="filter_based_on_selection(this.id)""`....

Comment: You can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in order to avoid simple bugs like this - Just give all the checkbox the same class and then use event delegation to bind the click event based on that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your code is because you're missing a closing quote around the `id` attribute, which is resulting in it being merged with the `onclick` attribute and messing up your logic. To fix this you simply need to add the `"` in the correct place.

That being said, you should really not be using `on*` event attributes at all any more. They are outdated and not good for separation of concerns.

Instead, attach your event handlers unobtrusively. As you've already included jQuery in the page, you can do that like this:

```js
var array2 = ['Z1', 'Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3', 'Z3', 'Z4', 'Z4', 'Z4', 'Z5', 'Z5', 'Z5', 'Z6', 'Z7', 'Z7'];

var html = array2.filter(function(v, i, a) {
  return a.indexOf(v) === i;
}).map(function(item) {
  return `<div class="checkbox"><label><input class="list-group2-item" id="${item}" type="checkbox" value="">${item}</label></div>`;
});

$('#filters').append(html).on('change', '.list-group2-item', function() {
  console.log('Selected option :', this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filters">
  <div class="list-group2"></div>
</div>
```

There's a couple of things to note here. Firstly I am building the HTML string to be appended once. This increases performance as it only requires 1 DOM access instead of once per each element of the array. Also it uses a delegated event handler, so it doesn't matter when you add the new checkboxes, the same event will be applied to them. Lastly, it uses the `change` event instead of the `click` event, which is better for UX and has better support for your visitors who navigate the web using the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong concatenation here:

```
'onclick="filter_based_o
^
```

Just adding a space and everthing works.

```js
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

function filter_based_on_selection(selected_box_id) {
  console.log("Selected option : ");
  console.log(selected_box_id);
}

array2 = ['Z1', 'Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3', 'Z3', 'Z4', 'Z4', 'Z4', 'Z5', 'Z5', 'Z5', 'Z6', 'Z7', 'Z7'];

var unique_account_groups = array2.filter(onlyUnique);

console.log("Unique Account Groups found : ");

console.log(unique_account_groups);

for (var prop in unique_account_groups) 
{
    jQuery("#filters").append('<div class="checkbox"><label><input class="list-group2-item" id= ' + unique_account_groups[prop] + ' onclick="filter_based_on_selection(this.id)" type="checkbox" value="">' + unique_account_groups[prop] + '</label></div>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filters">
  <div class="list-group2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just missed quotes around id, and one space before onclick.

Working example:

```js
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

function filter_based_on_selection(selected_box_id) {
  console.log("Selected option : ");
  console.log(selected_box_id);
}

array2 = ['Z1', 'Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3', 'Z3', 'Z4', 'Z4', 'Z4', 'Z5', 'Z5', 'Z5', 'Z6', 'Z7', 'Z7'];

var unique_account_groups = array2.filter(onlyUnique);

console.log("Unique Account Groups found : ");

console.log(unique_account_groups);

for (var prop in unique_account_groups) 
{
    jQuery("#filters").append('<div class="checkbox"><label><input class="list-group2-item" id=" ' + unique_account_groups[prop] + '" onclick="filter_based_on_selection(this.id)" type="checkbox" value="">' + unique_account_groups[prop] + '</label></div>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filters">
  <div class="list-group2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in a concatenation and a forgotten space,
I managed to make it work as below by changing a minimum of things :

```js
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

function filter_based_on_selection(selected_box_id) {
  console.log("Selected option :", selected_box_id);
}

array2 = ['Z1', 'Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3', 'Z3', 'Z4', 'Z4', 'Z4', 'Z5', 'Z5', 'Z5', 'Z6', 'Z7', 'Z7'];

var unique_account_groups = array2.filter(onlyUnique);
//console.log("Unique Account Groups found : ", unique_account_groups);

for (var prop in unique_account_groups){
    jQuery("#filters").append('<div class="checkbox"><label><input class="list-group2-item" id="' + unique_account_groups[prop] + '" onchange="filter_based_on_selection(this.id);" type="checkbox" value="">' + unique_account_groups[prop] + '</label></div>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filters">
  <div class="list-group2"></div>
</div>
```